# Integrate public API documentation with ChatGPT

Tags: openai-api

I have a website that has a public API documentation. I would like to integrate my search box with ChatGPT. My intention is that if a person types "*How to create an authenticated get locations call with Python, Ruby, or JavaScript*," even if the website does not have examples of Ruby, it should generate results as close as possible.

I know that https://openai.com/waitlist/plugins is on a waitlist, but I would like to discover general guidelines about:

- Feeding my API documentation data into ChatGPT (**main point of this question**)
- Integrating my search box into ChatGPT (I will figure this out)
- Displaying results (I will figure this out)

I could not find a specific documentation about "Feeding my API documentation data into ChatGPT". Is it possible to do it via API?

Answer (score 0):

No , ChatGPT does not allow feeding of data.

You need to use the OpenAI services for this and feed the GPT-3/4 model your data through.

You can use the fine tune APIs or can use the embedding APIs as well for this.